# How to delete specific rows and colums in matrices in cell array matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

Very new to coding and Matlab here!

I have a cell array (16*1) (1 column, 16 rows)
In each of the cells, I have one 76*76 matrix.

In each of the matrices, I'd like to delete certain rows (e.g. 1 to 10, 22 and 76) and the same columns (1 to 10, 22, and 76).

I have no idea how to go about that. I've tried to read the getting started documentation, but it's still unclear for me.. I'd be very appreciative of any help and explanation!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to delete elements. One is to assign [] to the rows and columns you want to delete, the other is to select what you want.

```
%some example data
x={magic(76),magic(76)}
%First option assign []
x{1}([1:10,22,76],:)=[]
x{1}(:,[1:10,22,76])=[]
%Second option, index what you need:
%All values from 11 to 75 without 22
selector=setdiff(11:75,22)
x{2}=x{2}(selector,selector)
```

Obviously instead of the hard coded {1} or {2}, you would call these in a for loop.

Some advice, when you have a cell of equally sized matrices and you want to perform the same operation on each of them, it is likely that a (76,76,16) is better suited for you. To stick with above example:

```
x=ones(76,76,16);
x=x(selector,selector,:);
```

All done in a single line.